# How to know what part of CPython is implemented in C?

Tags: python, c, optimization, cpython

Parts of the standard library of CPython that were written in C are faster than the parts that implemented in Python. To optimize the code, it would be good if one uses the functions which are implemented in C. My question is how can you determine or know the parts of the standard library is implemented in C?

Comment: By reading their docs?

Comment: I have zeal with both Python 2 and Python 3 documentation installed. They don't always mention whether something was implemented in C or not? It seems you haven't taken a look at the docs before @ lilezek

Comment: And what exactly would you do if something you want to use isn't implemented in C? Also the difference between C and Python is just a "constant factor" (typically 2-3 for functions exposed as Python functions), the right choice of algorithm and data structure however can be much more significant.

Comment: From the [standard docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html): `First, cPickle can be up to 1000 times faster than pickle because the former is implemented in C.`

Comment: This is only relevant to python 2. For instance, there is no `cPickle`, just `pickle` in python 3. By default it uses a C implementation (`_pickle`) if it can be found otherwise it falls back to a python implementation.

Comment: I was giving a example so that [MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393381/mseifert) will know that the factor is not 2-3. Let's not concentrate on that.

Answer (score 4):

> Parts of the standard library of CPython that were written in C are faster than the parts that implemented in Python. To optimise your code, it good if you use the functions and implemented in C.

While that's correct it's only half of the story. All builtins are implemented in C, a lot of standard-library modules are completely or partly implemented in C. So everything already *uses* C functions.

For example `collections.Counter` is a pure-Python class but the `collections._count_elements` function (Python 3) is implemented in C and used by `Counter` so that it can "count faster". But makes that `Counter` a C function?

So it's not a clear-cut thing and you shouldn't expect a Python part to be necessarily (much) slower than if it were implemented in C. Also "written in C" or "written in Python" is kind of an implementation detail. So what's written in Python now could be re-implemented as C functions in a future version (probably also vise-versa but that happens less frequently or not at all).

> how can you determine or know the parts of the standard library that were implemented in C?

You have to investigate that yourself. Some modules are available with a C implementation and a Python implementation (for example `StringIO` vs. `cStringIO` (python 2)) and other modules are completely implemented in C (for example `itertools`), others are partly implemented in C (for example `collections`).

Fortunately the CPython source code is available at [GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython) but it still requires to look at the [`Lib`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib) folder to check if there's a Python implementation. If there is no Python implementation it's almost certainly completely written in C but if there's a `.py` file (or in a subfolder) you still need to check what's imported there. For example [`collections`](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib) imports (and overrides) a lot of things from [`_collections`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c) which is implemented in C.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is how can you determine or know the parts of the standard library that were implemented in C?

You can read the sources of the standard library.

[Python Modules](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib)

[C modules](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Modules)

Or, what you should probably do, is measure the performance of your code, and then act based on that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Anything in the *Python Modules* link is implemented in Python and anything in the *C modules* link is implemented in C.